# Change default entity to search for in CRM 2011 when adding connection account

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011, under Account, there is the ability to add Connection. After clicking add Connection, you can browse/search for Name which defaults to "Contact". Is there a way to switch "Contact" to "Account" by default without having to switch the select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently is just doing this:

```js
document.getElementById("record2id").setAttribute("defaulttype", "1");
```

But i do a little search and this not work for the dialog of connections, check this [alternative](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/2da0a8bd-36e3-4b4c-a172-d2651f3826ce).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with connections.

With connections the object type code for the lookup is set in the Mscrm.Connection.preSelectObjectType function in Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb_static\entities\connection.js.

There is a line like

```
$v_2.set_defaultType($v_3);
```

where the object type is set. $v_3 is set depending on the chosen role.

So you need to change it to

```
$v_2.set_defaultType(Mscrm.EntityTypeCode.Account.toString());
```

But you will lose the role based lookup configuration, so you might want to modify that. Plus it is unsupported and you will need to take into account the updating behavior when installing new rollups that change the connection.js (i.e. copy newer connection.js files by hand from an updated system, and customize them again).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches. Both works, but the first adds the type record Icon to the loockup field even if it empy. The second doesn't do that but a little bit more risky as it depends on the internal method names.

1st method:

```
if (IsNull(Xrm.Page.getAttribute('record2id').getValue())) {$("#record2id")[0].DataValue = [{ "type": scrm.EntityTypeCode.SystemUser.toString() }];}
```

---

2nd Method

```
document.original_preSelectObjectType = Mscrm.Connection.preSelectObjectType;
Mscrm.Connection.preSelectObjectType = function (roleLookup, peerRoleLookup) {
   if (IsNull(roleLookup.DataValue) && IsNull(peerRoleLookup.DataValue) && !window.event.srcElement.DataValue) {
       var $v_0 = window.event.srcElement;
       $v_0.defaulttype = Mscrm.EntityTypeCode.SystemUser.toString();
       $v_0.DefaultViewId = "";
       $v_0.Lookup(true, false, null, false);
   }
   else { 
       document.original_preSelectObjectType(roleLookup, peerRoleLookup); }}
```

---